# Plotting logistic map

Tags: matlab, plot

I am currently trying to plot `f(x) = r*x*(1-x)` (where `r =3`) and `y=x` on the same graph by using:

```
syms r x;
f = symfun(r*x*(1-x), x)
r = 3
plot(f,x)
plot(x,x)
```

But my code keeps resulting in the error:

```
Error using plot
A numeric or double convertible argument is expected
```

Please can someone help point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error's pretty clear: pass a numeric argument to `plot`. You're feeding it a symbolic function. Just use

```
r = 3;
x = 0:0.1:10; %// set some x
f = (r.*x.*(1-x)); %// dots make the multiplication element-wise
figure; %// opens figure
hold on %// plots multiple things in one figure
plot(f,x)
plot(x,x,'r') %// produces a red plot
```

[image]